# What happens between Page.PreLoad and Page.Load events?

Tags: asp.net

Question is pretty straight forward.

Is there a technical reason for the existence of Page.PreLoad or is this just convenience to have a place where you can neatly place code that always have to be executed before the Load code?

Is there a difference between adding code in the PreLoad event handler and adding code at the top of the Load event handler?

And what would be a typical scenario where you use PreLoad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens between Page_PreLoad and Page_Load is that *all the other* PreLoad event handlers (not just the handler(s) you wrote) have a chance to run. **There is no reason to put code in Page_PreLoad.** You see, chances are that *you do want* to be sure all the other PreLoad event handlers have fired (I'll explain in the last paragraph). Plus, by using Page_Load instead of Page_PreLoad, you give control adapter authors a chance to override the behavior of your implementation.

The purpose of the Page.PreLoad event (as far as I can tell) is to provide a hook for control authors. The behavior of the load phase of the page lifecycle, is that the Load event is raised on the page before it is raised on all its child controls. As a control author, you might want to perform some action *after* viewstate is loaded (so Init is too early), but before Page_Load is called (so Load is too late). How you do that is to add an event handler to Page.PreLoad.

Some of the built-in ASP.NET data binding controls use this hook to be able to auto-magically re-DataBind themselves when you update the control in certain ways *after* its viewstate has been loaded. Using a flag set in Page.PreLoad, a control can distinguish between changes you make in Page_Init and changes you make in Page_Load. If you implement Page_PreLoad and you don't take care to avoid touching any control that hooks PreLoad in this way, *you're going to see undefined behavior* [because you don't know whether PreLoad is firing on the control or on the page first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645478/order-of-event-handler-execution). To avoid this complication, always use Page_Load instead, as there is no reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure I've answered this a few times, but you're best bet is to have a thorough read thorugh the **[ASP.NET Page Lifecycle Overview from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)** and the **[ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020102.htm)** explanation from [15 Seconds](http://www.15seconds.com).

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I've been checking out MSDN and I didn't find a definitive answer. MSDN simply states the PreLoad occurs before the Load. I can probably assume that nothing happens in between (or it would say so in the documentation), but I had a question in a sample MCTS exam about where to place some code, and  the correct answer was PreLoad and not Load. So I wondered if they're 100% technically correct..

Comment: yes, the code checked if Page.IsValid == true. I don't remember the exact requirement in the question, but i'll post it here if I run into the question again. It was something like "before processing the page, you must check if the page is valid". I think PreLoad was marked as correct because the Load answer didn't state "at the top of the Load function"..