# How to ensure the order of event handlers?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say that, in WPF, I have a following user control:

```
public partial class FlipButton : UserControl
{
    private Boolean _isOn = false;
}
public Boolean isOn
{
    get { return _isOn; }
    set { if (value) FlipBtn.Background = onColor;
          else FlipBtn.Background = offColor; _isOn = value; }
}
private void FlipBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    isOn = !isOn;
}
```

with a corresponding `<Button Name="FlipBtn" Click="FlipBtn_Click">` inside.

Now, I want to create a `FlipButtonGroup`, which holds a collection of those buttons laid out in a grid and has an internal collection of buttons in "enabled" state. It would have to update whenever a button is clicked, and there's my question: can I somehow guarantee that updating the `isOn` value will take place before the `FlipButtonGroup` handles the click?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Order of event handler execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645478/order-of-event-handler-execution). You may be able to rely on them being called in the order registered. This could break in the future though.