# Which event is raised after the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged has completed

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a comboBox that registers to `ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged`  event.
When that event is completed I want to do another change.

I tried to registered to `Combo_SelectionChangeCommitted` event but that event occures before the `ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged`

Does anyone know what event occurs after the `ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` is completed?

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      int selectedIndex = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
      Update(selectedIndex);
      ActiveNextRow(); // I want that method will occurred after the selectedIndexChanged event end.
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What other change do you need to do? Can it not be done as part of the SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: I need to active another control, I already try to do it, the result is the comboBox selection is not displayed.

Comment: Can you show some code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Can you explain more generally what it is you're trying to do? It looks like when the user selects a different item in the combo box you 'update' the item and then try and do 'ActiveNextRow' whatever that is.

Comment: After ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged() occurred I have to update the parent object , this update include a calculation that take time, therefore the selectedIndexChanged event isn't complete and I change the focus other object , therefore the I need to register to the event that raised when the   ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged finish.

Comment: I'm still not clear. Are you saying that when SelectedIndexChanged event is fired you update the parent object, which kicks off a long running calculation. After this has finished you then change the focus to another object, which is done by ActiveNextRow()?

Answer (score 0):

This question can be generalized to the order of events: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645478/order-of-event-handler-execution)

As an example you can do the following:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged3;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged2;
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
```

The execution order will be exactly as prescribed in the `Form1_Load` method. Another way to achieve what you want would be to put the call to your method at the end of the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method (in the same thread).

If your `Update` method runs some process on a separate thread, the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method will be completed before that process run by `Update` completes.